# Close specific notification android

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I need to close a specific notification that I click the buttom from it. The problem is how to know the notification_id to know which close. This is my code:

```
    intent.setAction("eliminar");
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("respuesta", 1);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);     


 pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                n  = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentTitle("Recordar")
                        .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(nota.getText()))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icono)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .setColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"))
                        .setOngoing(true) //notificacion persistente
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_borrar, "Quitar nota", pIntent).build();


                notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(cpos, n);
```

cpos is the id of every notification

Comment: If you raised the notification, you ought to know the ID you used. If you are asking how to clear other apps' notifications, thankfully, you can't do that.

Comment: Saying "I need to close a specific notification that I click the button from it", do you have button on your screen or on notification itself?

Comment: on notification itself I have the button

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to get notification ID based on the notification clicked. Using this ID you can identify which notification was clicked and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you :

> cpos is the id of every notification.

The above statement is false. Each notification has its own unique id which acts as the identifier for that notification.

You can use `notificationManager.cancel(cpos);` to clear the notification from status bar.

You can create a button and on click of that button you can call :

`notificationManager.cancel(cpos);`

to close your notification.

Comment: Yes but how I know if that id is of the notification that I want to close?

Comment: you yourself is creating the notification write? so you can use a integer array  to set the id of the notificationManager and accordingly you can cancel the  notification you want.

Comment: I have a sharedpreferences with the text of every notification and the id of of the notifications are the id of every text in the sharedpreferences. My problem is that don't know how to get the correct id

Comment: buddy its simple, lets assume you have two notifications to be shown and then you have two buttons to close those notifications. Now if the user clicks on any one of the cancel notification button then you can easily get the id of that notification you want to close from the sharedPreferences. And then finally you can cancel that notification using cancel method

Comment: But how i can get it? This is new for me and I don't have much idea about android notifications

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **ID of notification that is clicked**, 
try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194437/5089018) answer.

If you want to **show multiple notifications**, use this:-

Say you have created 2 notifications.
Make sure you give different *predefined* IDs to every notification.

eg.

**Notification 1:**

```
notificationManager.notify(1, n1);
```

**Notification 2:**

```
notificationManager.notify(2, n2);
```

***On button click:***

if condition matches condition1

```
notificationManager.cancel(1);
```

if condition matches condition2

```
notificationManager.cancel(2);
```

Comment: Maybe I should put the part of my code that cpos increment when I create a new notification. I have every ID in a sharepreferences but I don't know how to get the correct ID to know which notification I have to close. That is my problem, how to know the correct ID